# Point-Set Topology Proof Verification

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I am self-studying Baby Rudin (after some idleness) and his second chapter is on basic point-set topology.

Now, he asks the following:

Is every point of every open set $E\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ a limit point of $E$. Answer the same question for closed sets.

My answer was:

For closed sets, this is obviously false as seen through the case of a singleton set.

For open sets: (When I write a neighborhood of $x$, I mean the deleted neighborhood rather than the one with $x$)

Let $x$ be a non-limit point of $E$. Thus, $\exists N_1(x,r_1)\subset E^c$.

Assume $x\in E$ then $\exists N_2(x,r_2)$ such that $N_2(x,r_2)\subset E$.

There arises two cases:

a) $N_2\subset N_1\Rightarrow N_2\subset E^c \Rightarrow N_2=\phi$ since $N_2\subset E$ as well. Thus, $E=\{x\}$ which contradicts the fact that $E$ is open.

b) $N_1\subset N_2\Rightarrow N_1\subset E \Rightarrow N_1=\phi$ since $N_1\subset E^c$ as well.

However, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, no neighborhood is empty. (I believe this can be trivially proved for any $\mathbb{R}^n$ by connectedness of $\mathbb{R}$).

Thus, we have a contradiction and $x$ doesn't belong to $E$.

By law of contraposition, we proved that every point of $E$ is a limit point of $E$.

My doubt was the fact that I barely used the fact that $E\subset R^2$. I believe this is the fact that differentiates $E$ from another open set in some metric space where a neighborhood is allowed to be empty.

I hope someone would verify my proof. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Almost. One technical detail you acknowledge, but do not specifically address is that if $x\in N_2$ and $x\in E$, we cannot have $N_2\subseteq E^C$, but rather $N_2\subseteq E^C\cup\{x\}.$ Furthermore, in case (a), we cannot conclude that $E=\{x\}$, but only that $x$ is an isolated point of $E$ (picture an anulus with a single point in the middle). Also, your empty sets appear as $\phi$, not $\emptyset.$

Comment: Saying that $x$ is not a limit point of $E$ is not equivalent to saying $\exists\,N(x,r)\subseteq E^c$.  Consider any isolated point.  It is not a limit point but every neighborhood contains the point itself.

Comment: Do it directly: Every open set in $R^{n}$ is a union of open balls of the form $B_{r}(x)$ so if we pick for each $n\in N$ an $x_{n}\neq x\in B_{1/n}(x)\cap E$ (it's an open set in $R^{n}$ so we may do this)  then we get a sequence of points $\left \{ x_{n} \right \}\subset E$ converging to $x$ which says $x$ is a limit point of $E$.

Comment: I did say in the beginning that I meant deleted neighborhoods... I just don't know how to write the notation for it in LaTeX so I just said it verbally.

Comment: @Chilango intuitively you're correct, but it is not proved that every open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is of that form. So I can't really use that proof unfortunately, at least until I read the proof of the lemma you used (I'll google it.)

Also , sorry for writing the empty set like that. Been some time since I last used LaTeX.

Comment: There's no intuition here. We are  just usng the definition of the toplogy on $R^{n}$ induced by the usual metric $d:R^{n}\rightarrow R$

Comment: Definition of topology? He didn't even define the word topology. This is an Analysis book but it has basic topology because it'll be needed later on. But anyway, I googled it and yeah, I think I get it though I doubt Rudin intended this to be used. Thanks though, a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks correct, but I think your statements about "no neighborhood being empty" are missing the main idea here. In fact, $\emptyset$ is open in every topology, so it's a neighborhood in $\mathbb R^2$. It's just that since it doesn't contain any points, it's not a neighborhood of any point.

What you're meaning to say is that the *punctured* neighborhoods $N_1 \setminus \{x\}$ and $N_2 \setminus \{x\}$ cannot be empty. This is equivalent to the statement that no singleton set in $\mathbb R^2$ is open. This really is something which is special to $\mathbb R^2$ (and many other topological spaces) but doesn't hold even for general metric spaces. For instance, $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb R$ is a metric space, but it has the discrete topology, meaning that every subset of $\mathbb Z$ is open in its topology. So indeed, not every point of an open subset of $\mathbb Z$ is a limit point of that set. In fact, no point is a limit point for any subset of $\mathbb Z$!

Comment: Thanks, but still AlexS's comment about case (a) seems to render my proof wrong. I think the correction is just to put (b) before (a) rendering (a) as the only case. Then, for all $N_2\subset N_1$ $N_2\cap E={x}$ and when $N_2$ is not a subset of $N_1$, there is a contradiction and thus this means that $E=\{x\}$. Also, I noted that I meant the deleted (punctured) neighborhoods before I began but wrote $N$ to avoid confusion. Also, your definition of a neighborhood is different, it seems because the empty set isn't considered one in my book.